Outlook not applying a rule to a Group mailbox (mailbox belongs to a MS Teams site)
I have a question on applying a rule to my own MS Teams site.  According to Microsoft, you can right-click on an email and you'll see rule appear as an option.  This works in my own forename.surname@mydomain.com email address.  My question relates to my Teams site mailbox, DT01 - as you see in the picture below, there is no rule option.

Is the problem somehow permissions in Teams?  Although I am the owner of the Teams site in question.
Or is it an Outlook permissions problem?  I think this must be the problem.  I can set rules on my own Inbox and, in fact, I could create a rule, specify it to run on DT01, but it just doesn't do apply the rule and move the test email to the junk folder.  BTW - I found the value 'DT01' as a group within the Outlook menu.
The rule works off key words 'move me', 'asthma' or 'serious' in the subject line of the email.  The key words are satisfied, but the rule is not applied, so the email is not moved.

Any suggestions please?

Does this shared mailbox have a user license applied to it? In order for rules to function on a mailbox it must have a license applied to it. Shared mailboxes, by default, do not have licenses applied to them. You will need to speak with your Exchange Admins, licensing admins, and probably purchasing (because licenses have costs) regarding this.

Hi, ah that'll be the reason, no it doesn't have a user license applied to it.  Thanks for the suggestion, I think you've cracked it!

Please note that questions regarding enterprise computing environments are largely off topic on this site. As such, this question will rightly be closed and deleted. Official IT admins are generally welcomed, but it is helpful that they state that is their role so we know the context their questions exist in. If you are a user and not an admin, you should be speaking with your org IT support and not asking here.

I'm responsible for the Sharepoint system and am now working Teams / M365.  Would this question be more suited to the general Stack Exchange perhaps?  I'm puzzled as to which is the correct forum, as Super User, on the face of it at least, appeared to me to be a bit of a catch-all.  Thanks in any case for your help.

ServerFault is for sysadmins and enterprise level software stuff. But, also, I found this answer by doing a quick web search. As a sysadmin myself, who has used these sites, many, MANY times to solve work problems in enterprise systems, we need to make sure we've done the research, tried the things, and then document that as we ask questions, and then our questions will be better received. Especially over on SF, the quality of knowledge is really, REALLY good, but the standards and expectations are rather high as well. If your Q can be answered with a web search, it might get poor reception.

Seems like your CAPS LOCK is getting stuck at random?  Have a nice evening/morning/afternoon

As far as I know, rules are generally applied to the emails sent and received by the corresponding account, and you can choose to use rules for emails received by the root account, and move them with specific rules to the folder of the shared mailbox associated with the root account.
According to the rules set by your picture display, based on my understanding, some settings are created for your main account after receiving the email, but these settings will not be forwarded to the shared mailbox, that is, the email you receive is forwarded to the shared mailbox through the corresponding rules, and will only appear in the inbox of the shared mailbox, perhaps you need to set rules for shared mailboxes.
In addition, i find a thread that mentioned Create mailbox rule in Powershell, please feel free to refer to.
Hope it helps!
